# Определить показан ли div элемент на странице и передать результат php

Tags: php, jquery, css

На странице есть `div.box`, который может быть спрятан `display: none;` если `@media only screen and (max-width: 157px)`
Как php-скрипту передать данные о том, что `div.box` спрятан?

Как проверить на jQuery мне известно:

```
var $box = $(".box");

if ($box.is(":hidden"))
{
    но не более того...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До загрузки страницы никак.  А потом лишь используя Аякс. Вы бы сказали зачем конкретно это нужно. Но судя по вопросу у вас только Аякс в распоряжении.

Comment: Для сбора статистики. Чтобы засчитать показ, если пользователь видит блок. До загрузки или перезагрузки, не понял это!?

Comment: @Plush отправляйте в нужный вам момент времени (после загрузки страницы, или после какого-то действия пользователя, или когда-либо ещё) Ajax-запрос на сервер (PHP-скрипту) с необходимой информацией.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже кто-то заметил - ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: <путь до скрипта, который будет обрабатывать запрос>, 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {
          jsonData: $.toJSON(<какая-либо информация>)
          },
    success: function(){
          <callback, который будет выполняться в случае успешной передачи данных>
          }
    });
```

Данные в формате json можно обрабатывать функцией json_encode(), которая вернет массив с нужной информацией.